# Return value from 2nd line in string

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am trying to return the 2nd line from a field containing a string. I have tried indexof and split, and it gets me close, but have not had success using the newline \n.

How can I return "Assignment Group:  TI-BSM-Tech Monitoring" or ideally "TI-BSM-Tech Monitoring" from the string below.

```
Call-out:  true 
Assignment Group:  TI-BSM-Tech Monitoring 
Data String - index=cisco_ise sourcetype=cisco:ise:syslog source=* Alert when critical services are no longer logging Hourly
```

Some code I have tried

```
var description = "Call-out:  true Assignment Group:  TI-BSM-Tech Monitoring next String - index=cisco_ise sourcetype=cisco:ise:syslog source=* Alert when critical services are no longer logging Hourly".split('Assignment Group:')[1];

var assignment = description.substring(description.indexOf('Group:  ') + 2);

console.log(assignment);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pretty answer, but not sure how else you'd do it. Split by `Assignment Group:`, then `"\n"`. You have to use double-quotes to trap a newline character

```js
let description = document.querySelector('textarea').value;

let assignment = description.split('Assignment Group:')[1].split("\n")[0].trim();

console.log(assignment);
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="50">
Call-out:  true 
Assignment Group:  TI-BSM-Tech Monitoring 
Data String - index=cisco_ise sourcetype=cisco:ise:syslog source=* Alert when critical services are no longer logging Hourly
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with a regular expression

```js
let description = document.querySelector('textarea').value;

// skip everything until Assignment Group, read everything that isn't a newline, discard everything else
// m is the multi-line flag

let assignment = description.replace(/^.*\nAssignment Group:\s+([^\n]+).*\n.*$/m,'$1');

document.getElementById("output").textContent = assignment;
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="50">
Call-out:  true 
Assignment Group:  TI-BSM-Tech Monitoring 
Data String - index=cisco_ise sourcetype=cisco:ise:syslog source=* Alert when critical services are no longer logging Hourly
</textarea>
<br>
<output id="output">
</output>
```